# Sync clock derived from AC power source

Tags: clock

I am developing a wireless device which stores data by sampling an Analogue sensor at a specific time. The only 'wires' to this device are the two power wires. I am using a 12V AC power supply and I am wondering if I can send a 'clock' signal using the power line. The clock rate I am looking to achieve is from 10Hz to 400Hz. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this. 
Many Thanks
Stuart.

Comment: Just use the 50/60Hz of your AC mains and multiply/divide accordingly.

Comment: @PlasmaHH not sure that is the question...

Comment: The question relates to providing digital signal across the AC power lines, aka internet from the 110v/220v receptacle

Comment: @Anonymous: at 400Hz I doubt that it has anything to do with internet, also "wireless device" seems to relate to the way of communication, as it already has wires for power, so can't be about it being battery operated.

Comment: You can send a high frequency signal "on top" of low frequency AC.  A short "spike" should be fairly easy to couple into the AC source, and then recover pn the receiving end.

Comment: But, Plasmahh has the simplest solution.  Trigger on a multiple of the line frequency.  Use a divider and a PLL for multiples of line frequency, or just a divider for fractions of line frequency.

Answer (score 2):

AC power supplies convert voltage from mains power, which is 50/60Hz depending on where you live.  If you can use *any* clock between 10 and 400Hz, then you can produce a clock by feeding it into a comparator/Schmitt Trigger with a ground reference:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvfH67.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you need a specific frequency other than 50/60Hz that is a multiple of 50/60Hz, you can multiply/divide the frequency.  If you need adjustable frequency, you could use any sort of RC-controlled oscillator or a programmable timer/counter on a microcontroller.